# How to automatically clicking/refreshing live data of API output from python to Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I had pulled live data using APIs on python and displayed the output in Tkinter.
The problem is my live data only updated when I click "refresh"(the button that I created). I'm seeking a solution on how to keep my live data update by a second without clicking the "refresh" button that I created or a way to click the "refresh" automatically in an infinite loop since my live data is changing every second.

[image]
[image]

I do very much appreciated in advance for any advice and solution.

Please take a look into my code

```
root = Tk()
root.title("test_app")
root.geometry("500x500")


Extbutton = Button(root, text=" Exit ", command=exit).place(x=0,y=140), 
Refreshbutton = Button(root, text="refresh", command=data).place(x=0,y=110),
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `after` method to schedule a function to run after a delay given in milliseconds. The following will arrange for `data` to be called after 1 second has elapsed:

```
root.after(1000, data)
```

If you put that at the bottom of the `data` function, it will automatically schedule itself to be called every second for as long as the program is running.